# Why does this bash/sed call work?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've been looking at examples of using sed to extract a substring using regex and I have a test script working.  Problem is I don't understand why and would like to.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="       ID  : s0016b54e23bc.ab.cd.efghig\
Name : cd167095"
echo -e "string: '$string'"
name=`echo $string | sed 's/.*\(cd.*\)/\1/'`
echo -e "\nExtracted: $name"
```

And it outputs:

```
string: '       ID  : s0016b54e23bc.ab.cd.efghigName : cd167095'

Extracted: cd167095
```

The regex should have two matches:

```
cd.efghigName : cd167095
```

and

```
cd167095
```

Why is the second match returned?

Comment: I'm confused. You say your example yields "extracted: mta16..." and that is not remotely in your example input?

Comment: Oops, I simplified the example data and missed updating one line.  Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Because it's "greedy"

The first `.*` matches as much as possible for the expression as a whole to succeed.

To see this, change the second `cd` to `ef` or something, and you will see the script return the first.

Now, if you use something like Ruby, Python, or Perl, you get more elaborate regular expressions, and you can use `.*?` which is the "non-greedy" form of `.*`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

string="       ID  : s0016b54e23bc.ab.cd.efghig\
Name : cd167095"
puts string.gsub /.*?(cd.*)/, '\1'
so ross$ ./qq3
cd.efghigName : cd167095
```

Though really, I would just write:

```
string[/cd.*/]
```

Comment: I still don't get it.  My understanding of greedy is that the longer match would be returned, but it's the shorter one that is.  Reading the "Lazy quantification" section from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), the example they give returns the longer string as well.

Comment: You are correct, the longer match is returned. And the first regular expression *is* returning the longer match. If the *entire expression* were "cd.*" then it would return both "cd" strings, but you first have a ".*" and by the time that's finished being greedy, there is only one "cd" left.